# What is the most efficient (fastest) way to write to a file every few milliseconds?

Tags: c++, windows

I need to open a file, write a byte to a file every few milliseconds, and close the file.  What is the most efficient way of doing this?  At the moment, it is causing high CPU utilization.

Comment: Keep the file open. 90% or more of this CPU time is used in opening and closing.

Comment: not use C++ :-), no joke, any example of how you are doing that -> code?

Comment: Since you are on Windows/C++, I'd say the API WriteFile() is one of the most efficient ways... but if you are flushing the file after each small write, the bottleneck will not be in your code for sure.

Comment: `I need to...` I think you need to rethink how you do things, and get rid of the file.

Comment: That would be about the _least_ efficient way. You really need to keep that file open, or write to a large enough buffer, and then write that buffer to disk.

Comment: What is your outer problem? I can't think of any problem for which writing to a file every few milliseconds would be a sensible solution on a general purpose OS like Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to write files is using the system APIs. Since you are on Windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540534(v=vs.85).aspx

```
HANDLE hfile = CreateFile("file",              // name of the write
                       GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
                       0,                      // do not share
                       NULL,                   // default security
                       CREATE_NEW,             // create new file only
                       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
                       NULL);                  // no attr. template
bErrorFlag = WriteFile( 
                    hfile,           // open file handle
                    DataBuffer,      // start of data to write
                    dwBytesToWrite,  // number of bytes to write
                    &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
                    NULL);           // no overlapped structure

CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Also, open the file when the application is being loaded, and close the file when the application is being destroyed, because opening and closing files is the slow part. That is, don't open/close the file every time you need to write, but instead, only once.

These functions reside in `<windows.h>`.

Comment: Although, I'm not creating a new file, I'm actually writing a byte into a specific position in the middle of the file.  Does that make a difference because I assume I'll need to fseek to the correct spot each time I write.

Comment: @youcantexplainthat How can keeping the file open *not* make a difference? How can it possibly not be more efficient than opening and closing the file every few ms?